# Vector type-recipe plotting in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-plots

Is there a way to write a plotting type recipe for a type `T` and then have Julia somehow infer a corresponding recipe for the type `Vector{T}`?

Simple example, suppose I have a box struct `B`, and I write a simple type-recipe for plotting it:

```
using Plots

struct B x0;x1;y0;y1 end
bshape(b::B) = Shape([b.x0,b.x1,b.x1,b.x0],[b.y0,b.y0,b.y1,b.y1])
@recipe f(::Type{B}, b::B) = bshape(b)
```

So now `plot(B(0,1,2,3))` plots a filled rectangle like I wanted. Now say I have an array of `B`s, and I want to plot all the rectangles in a single plot by calling `plot(bs)`. Simply defining the type recipe for `B` doesn't accomplish this. I can write another type recipe for vectors of `B` like this:

```
@recipe f(::Type{Vector{B}}, bs::Vector{B}) = bshape.(bs)
```

But, first of all, I don't really love this, it's got some repeated code. I'd rather be able to tell Julia to just use the original type recipe.  Also, e.g., if I want to let each box be able to determine other things about how it gets plotted, say:

```
@recipe function f(::Type{B}, b::B)
    fillcolor --> (b.x0==0 ? :red : :blue)
    bshape(b)
end
```

At this point the vector version, as written above, won't do what I want. I can probably modify it somehow, but it seems like there should be a "correct" way to do this.